# How to start a song in jPlayer in the middle on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

Hi i have a jPlayer embeded in a page

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: playList[0]
          }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3"
      });
    changeSong(0);
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.ended + ".jp-repeat", function(event) { // Using ".jp-repeat" namespace so we can easily remove this event
  });

});
```

Here the variable array playlist is previously defined. Also i am binding an event to change the song when it reaches its end.

These things work perfectly.

What i want is to play the song not from begining but from say 50% and it should auto play.

the

> .jPlayer("play");

part in the code auto plays the thing. How do i move it to 50%? it should be done as soon as it starts to play without the user noticing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be an elegant solution, But this is what i did

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: playList[0]
          }).jPlayer("play");
        },
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3"
      });
    changeSong(0);
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.ended + ".jp-repeat", function(event) { // Using ".jp-repeat" namespace so we can easily remove this event
  });
  pushForwardTimeInSong();
//other codes
//
//
function pushForwardTimeInSong()
{
    setTimeout("$('#jquery_jplayer_1').jPlayer('playHead', 50);",2000);
}
```

I called a new function there and let that move the player head after 2secs.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this, but what does changeSong function makes?

try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
       setInterval( function () {
         var duration = $(this).duration;
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3: playList[0]
          }).jPlayer("play");
        }, duration-10000),
        swfPath: "js",
        supplied: "mp3"
      });
    changeSong(0);
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").bind($.jPlayer.event.ended + ".jp-repeat", function(event) { // Using ".jp-repeat" namespace so we can easily remove this event
  });

});
```

This will start the music 10 secs before the other starts.

Comment: changeSong functions changes the song to next song when 1 song finishes. Will try this out and tell what happens

Comment: This is not working. I think you have misunderstood my question.